# Linear regression different using R plot() and qplot()

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

If I create a scatterplot using `plot()` with `lm(x~y)` on my data I get intercept at 500 and when I observe the `qplot` on the same data with `stat_smooth(method=lm)`, the intercept is at roughly 1000 on y axis. Although the slope looks visually similar to that on the simple `plot()`. I hope this makes sense. I cannot understand why the difference. Full functions are given below. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

`plot()`:

```
plot (my[[12]],my[[8]])
abline(lm(my[[12]]~my[[8]]),col="red")
```

`qplot()`:

```
myGG<-qplot(x=my[[12]],y=my[[8]])                        # pretty scatterplot
myGG<-myGG + stat_smooth(fullrange=TRUE,method="lm")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that the variables in the regressions do not correspond. In `lm` the variable `my[[12]]` is **dependent**, in the `qplot` variant it is the **independent** one. Using `lm(my[[8]]~my[[12]]` should make it equivalent.

It is a common mistake to mix up the variables when using `plot` and `lm`. Note that to get the axis right, the order of the variables changes in `lm` compared to `plot`.

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
plot(x,y)
abline(lm(y ~x))
```

To make it less confusing you might use the formula interface in `plot` as well.

```
plot(y ~ x)
abline(lm(y ~x))
```